# ./mach bootstrap is not working in windows 10 cmd

Tags: firefox, mozilla

I am building firefox on windows 10 and i have follow and the steps mentioned in [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Windows_Prerequisites) link

Once I checkout the firefox source code using this cmd

```
hg clone https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central
```

and after that I type `"./mach bootstrap"` to catch all the dependencies

It is giving me below  error

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I have install all the software and libraries but still it is not working.

Is there anything i am missing and doing something wrong?

Comment: It seems that you're not running `./mach bootstrap` from within the Mozilla Build Tools shell, as instructed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Windows_Prerequisites#Getting_the_source). This command will only work when executed within the Build Tools shell.

Comment: Yes, Thanks Dexter, there was some build in config issues with the Mozilla build tools and it is working fine now.